# Windows USB dongle for LoRa/LoRaWan and BT5/BLE

Tags: usb, windows, bluetooth-5, lora

I want to play around with LoRa/LoRaWan and BT5/BLE on an ESP32. I would like to pair the ESP32 with my Windows laptop and do some server side development on the laptop.

Can you recommend a cheap Windows compatible USB dongle?